Adding and rigging a dress to an already rigged lowpoly character
So I had an already rigged a lowpoly character, and I want to add a dress, so far all I did was make the Dress, align it to the character and parented it to the armature using automatic weights, please help!



So you didn't say what is the problem, what you could do though is create a series of bones that will control the dress itself? Maybe share your file so that we can give a try

Thanks for the reply, so the issue is that the legs are clipping through the skirt, how should I add the .blend file so that you could try to help me do something about it?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

https://blend-exchange.com/b/dyOZ1Z84 thanks in advance

As you can see if you select a vertex of the dress it is part of vertex group it should not be part of (picture), so you'll need to remove manually (with the Remove button under the Vertex Groups list in the Data panel) or in Weight Paint mode, or if it's to complicated to have bones that control both the legs and the dress, create new bones to control the dress only.

